# Is it possible to customize the antd TimePicker HH from 00 to 99 instead of 00 to 23?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./index.css";
import { TimePicker } from "antd";
import type { Dayjs } from "dayjs";

const format = "HH:mm";
const Demo: React.FC = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<Dayjs | null>(null);

  const onChange = (time: Dayjs | null) => {
    setValue(time);
  };

  return <TimePicker value={value} onChange={onChange} format={format} />;
};

export default Demo;
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, you want a timepicker with invalid ranges? Then don't use a timepicker?

Comment: I know, its invalid range, but is it possible to extend the HH?

Comment: Probably not no, that would be strange and defeat the purpose of a timepicker component. Why don't you just use an `<input type="number">`?

Comment: Its a bit tricky requirement from the team,

Comment: This is not possible, is a time/hour picker, a day only have 24 hours so you cannot extend it until 99.

Comment: Surely there is nothing built-in to customize the number of hours on a day. Especially because the return value has to be compatible with a `Date` object. What would `2023-06-24T67:56:00` even mean (if it were possible)

Answer (score 3):

Generally, it's impossible if you're supposed to use a standard ant design library.

The hour range is based on the format prop, which follows the dayjs format specification. The dayjs format specification only supports HH for 24-hour format and hh for 12-hour format, but not any other hour range.

One possible solution is that you fork and modify antd module in github.
Or you can create your own custom component.

For example:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { InputNumber } from "antd";

type Props = { onChange?: (value: string) => void; defaultValue?: string };
const TIME_TYPE = {
  HOUR: "hour",
  MINUTE: "minute",
  SECOND: "second",
};

const getTimeString = (
  hour: number,
  minute: number,
  second: number
): string => {
  return (
    hour.toString().padStart(2, "0") +
    ":" +
    minute.toString().padStart(2, "0") +
    ":" +
    second.toString().padStart(2, "0")
  );
};

const CustomTimePicker: React.FC<Props> = ({
  onChange,
  defaultValue,
}: Props) => {
  const [hour, setHour] = useState<number>(0);
  const [minute, setMinute] = useState<number>(0);
  const [second, setSecond] = useState<number>(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const initialize = () => {
      if (defaultValue) {
        const [defaultHour, defaultMinute, defaultSecond] =
          defaultValue.split(":");
        setHour(parseInt(defaultHour));
        setMinute(parseInt(defaultMinute));
        setSecond(parseInt(defaultSecond));
      }
    };
    initialize();
  }, [defaultValue]);

  const handleChange = (value: number, type: string): void => {
    let timeString = "";
    switch (type) {
      case TIME_TYPE.HOUR:
        setHour(value);
        timeString = getTimeString(value, minute, second);
        break;
      case TIME_TYPE.MINUTE:
        setMinute(value);
        timeString = getTimeString(hour, value, second);
        break;
      default:
        setSecond(value);
        timeString = getTimeString(hour, minute, value);
        break;
    }

    onChange && onChange(timeString);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <InputNumber
        min={0}
        max={99}
        defaultValue={0}
        value={hour}
        onChange={(value) => handleChange(value || 0, TIME_TYPE.HOUR)}
      />
      :
      <InputNumber
        min={0}
        max={60}
        defaultValue={0}
        value={minute}
        onChange={(value) => handleChange(value || 0, TIME_TYPE.MINUTE)}
      />
      :
      <InputNumber
        min={0}
        max={60}
        defaultValue={0}
        value={second}
        onChange={(value) => handleChange(value || 0, TIME_TYPE.SECOND)}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default CustomTimePicker;
```

You can use this custom component like this:

```
<CustomTimePicker onChange={console.log} defaultValue="99:00:00" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To customize the range of the `TimePicker` component in Ant Design (`antd`) to include hours from 00 to 99 instead of the default 00 to 23, you'll need to make some modifications to the component. Here's how you can achieve that:

```
import React from "react";
import { TimePicker } from "antd";
import dayjs from "dayjs";

class CustomTimePicker extends React.Component {
 // Override the format function to display hours from 00 to 99
 format = value => {
   return value ? value.format("HH") : "";
 };

 // Override the parser function to handle user input of hours from 00 to 99
 parser = value => {
   const intValue = parseInt(value, 10);
   if (isNaN(intValue)) return undefined;
   if (intValue < 0 || intValue > 99) return undefined;
   return dayjs().hour(intValue);
 };

 render() {
   // Destructure props to pass down any additional props to the underlying TimePicker component
   const { ...restProps } = this.props;

   return (
     <TimePicker
       format={this.format}
       parser={this.parser}
       {...restProps}
     />
   );
 }
}
```

then use the CustomTimePicker component in your code wherever you want to display the modified time picker:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <CustomTimePicker />
    </div>
  );
};
```

The modified `CustomTimePicker` component overrides the `format` and `parser` functions to handle the display and input of hours from 00 to 99. The `format` function ensures that the displayed value is always in the "HH" format, and the `parser` function handles user input and converts it back to a valid Day.js object.

As mentioned before in othre comments, allowing input of hours from 00 to 99 may not adhere to standard time conventions, and it's generally recommended to use the default 00 to 23 range for hours. Customizing it to 00-99 might lead to confusion for users and may not be suitable for most scenarios.

Comment: Sorry, it does not work,
UI still showing 00 to 23 hours, but it should be 00 to 99 hours,
and If I select a time from the TimePicker, its not selecting properly, selecting only hour, but there are also minute and second options there.